# Converting vector<char> to const char* and string

Tags: c++, string, iterator, char, stdvector

How to convert vector to const char* ? Also to string?
Is this even legal?

```
void Printer::Wrap(const CharVector& text, RangeVector& result) const
    //if (TestLineWidth(text.begin(), text.end()))
    int c = 0;
    for (CharVector::const_iterator it = text.begin(); it != text.end(); ++it)
        c++;
    if (TestLineWidth(&text[0], &text[c]))
```

Here are declarations of CharVector and TestLineWidth:

```
typedef std::vector<char> CharVector;

bool TestLineWidth(const char* from, const char* to) const;
```

Comment: in c++11 there is a method [std::vector::data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data). For older versions you can use `&text[0]`. But keep in mind that c-string is a nullterminated string and vector might not have null at the end

Comment: Why is there a vector<char> involved? Why not using std::string? It is exactly made for this!

Comment: @Klaus maybe there is a byte array that might contain not only strings or not only single string like in some implementations of HTTP clients.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<char> data = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '!'};
    cout << string(begin(data), end(data)) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For const char *, you cant just call data.data(), becouse C-string are null terminated, so you'll have to append '\0' at the end

Comment: I'm not sure I understood:
what I have is vector<char> data, and what I need is const char*
I can't do it like in commented line, data.begin(), data.end()

Comment: If you need const char *, use string(begin(data), end(data)).c_str()

Comment: Thanks. And how can I know begin and end of const char* ? Could you see the function of my code posted in original question?

Answer (score -1):

And if you want to convert the string into a char* you can use yourString.c_str()
cf C++ documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

Comment: I'm trying to convert vector<char> to const char*

Comment: I mean you have to create a string before from your vector<char> (using the Patryk solution) and then create a char* from this string.

Comment: OK, but this function I have needs to know beginning and end of the char* (commented function TestLineWidth)

Comment: In fact if you are using at least C++11 you can use non-member begin() and end() http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570638/Ten-Cplusplus-Features-Every-Cplusplus-Developer#beginend

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. I can create string from vector, I can turn that string to const char*, but look at my function - I need vector.begin(), and vector.end(), which must be turned to const char*